# RewriteRule category use

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use URL rewrite for category view:

```
example.com/technology/                  --> for main category page
example.com/technology/awesome-new-video --> for articles
```

I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule technology/(.*) /view.php?cat=technology&short_url=$1
```

It's works fine, but I can't open this URL to get the category page: (without the last slash character)

```
example.com/technology
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, It is possible :)

Comment: RewriteRule technology(/(.*))? /view.php?cat=technology&short_url=$2

Comment: Can you tell me how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule so that the slash and everything after it is optional:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^technology(?:/(.*)|)$ /view.php?cat=technology&short_url=$1 [L]
```